# SQLite SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? Troubles

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, node.js

There's a gap in my knowledge here and I can't find the answer on the internet.

Basically I'm making a node.js app that pushes entries from an SQLite Database using socket.io.

I'm using the implementation of SQLite here -> https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3

I'm trying to execute the statement:

```
db.serialize(function() {
        db.run("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id=?", messageNum, function(err, row) {
            console.log(row.id);            
        });
    });
```

I can't find documentation. It's throwing this error at the moment:

Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I basically guessed the syntax... Anyone know what it actually is?

**EDIT**

I have got around the problem with an extremely inefficient solution for now:

```
db.serialize(function() {

        db.each("SELECT id, msg, date FROM messages", function(err, row) {
            if(row.id === messageNum){
                console.log(row.id);    
            }
        });

    });
```

Would be good if someone could point me in the right direction at some point though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) – the `run` function does not return any data.

The `each` function supports parameters, just like `run`:

```
db.each("SELECT id, msg, date FROM messages WHERE id = ?",
        messageNum,
        function(err, row) {
            console.log(row.id);
        });
```

Comment: Actually, run does have some properties that are accessible in a callback.